# TSQL transaction checking both @@ERROR and @@ROWCOUNT after a statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions

I can rollback a transaction if an error occurs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
(
   @Param1  [int] 
)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Param1
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET    Col2 = 'something'
WHERE Col1 = @Param1

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN -12
END
...
```

But if there are no entries in the `Table1` with the `Col1 = @Param1` transaction commits successfully, which is bad for me. I'd like to check if `Col2 = 'something'` is really done. If not, then rollback with a particular return code.
If I try to insert `@@rowcount` check after `@@error` check, like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
(
   @Param1  [int] 
)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Param1
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET    Col2 = 'something'
WHERE Col1 = @Param1

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN -12
END

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN -27
END
...
```

it always rollbacks at this point, because `@@rowcount` evaluates the very last statement so it always equals `0`.

How in such a case to check both the `@@error` and the number of rows affected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Store both into your own variables in a single query, then check:

```
DECLARE @rc int
DECLARE @err int
SELECT @Param1
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET    Col2 = 'something'
WHERE Col1 = @Param1
SELECT @rc = @@ROWCOUNT,@err = @@ERROR

IF @err <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN -12
END

IF @rc = 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN -27
END
```